# AWS IOT analytics to trigger event when attribute changes state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-analytics

Is it possible to detect if an attribute of an iOT message changed say from false to true and trigger an action?  I would like to capture all status changes.
I'm wondering if iot analytics is the right tool for this.
Going through the tutorial it appears that choosing a delta time window and querying the data could trigger an event.
The smaller the time window would be the more real time my alarm would be. One problem I see with this is that alarm would be repeatedly triggered.
Is this in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options available, depending on what action you'd like to trigger and the specific conditions that should trigger it.

- [AWS IoT Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rules.html) are typically used for routing the incoming messages based on some condition (eg: if a certain attribute in the message is `true` or `false`). This is a "stateless" form of trigger, as each message is processed/routed independently.
- [AWS IoT Events](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-events/) may be better suited for a "stateful" trigger (eg: alarm when the first message is received with a change in the field value)
- [AWS IoT Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/welcome.html) include another mechanism that can be used to react to specific conditions in the messages received ("stateless" trigger), in the form of the [Lambda Activity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/pipeline-activities.html#aws-iot-analytics-pipeline-activities-lambda) that can be associated with a processing Pipeline